# WordPress: wp_cron which should delete all posts in trash at every 10 a.m. EST

Tags: wordpress, cron

I used Automatically Empty Trash after the number of days the user requires. The user can set the number of days from which the trash should be automatically deleted. But I need to delete all posts in the trash at every 10 a.m. EST.

Anyone, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

you need a cron scheduler 
try modifying this code at your needs :

```
    <?php
add_action('my_hourly_event', 'do_this_hourly');

function my_activation() {
    if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'my_hourly_event' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'my_hourly_event');
    }
}
add_action('wp', 'my_activation');

function do_this_hourly() {
    // do something every hour
}
?>
```

reference from [here](http://wp-snippets.com/schedule-cron-jobs-with-wordpress/)